# Simpler way to show $v$ must be zero?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, orthogonality

Let $x$ and $y$ be linearly independent vectors in $\mathbf{R}^2$. If $v \in \mathbf{R}^2$ is orthogonal to both $x$ and $y$, then $v$ is the zero vector.

Here's my proof:

Since $x$ and $y$ are linearly independent, they span $\mathbf{R}^2$. So we can write $v = ax+by$ for some real values $a,b$. If $a=0$ then we would have $v=by$, which would imply $b=0$. If $a \ne0$, then we can write $x = a^{-1}(v-by)$. Then we have

$$0 = \langle x, v \rangle = \langle a^{-1}(v-by), v \rangle = a^{-1}\langle u, u \rangle - ba^{-1} \langle y,u \rangle = a^{-1}\langle u, u \rangle,$$

so we must have $u=0$.

Is there a simpler way to show this? In particular, I think we should be able to do this without my first argument about $x$ and $y$ spanning $\mathbf{R}^2$.

Comment: If the two vectors do not span $\mathbb R$, then $v$ may not be zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the fact that $x,y$ span $\mathbb R^2$ is the crucial argument here. Suppose that there is some vector $w\in \mathbb R^2$ not spanned by $x$ and $y$, then $w$ would be a counterexample for your claim,